# How to keep calling a function while a variable is false

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a script that allows me to delete items from a DB API but this requires me to paginate through the pages. My question is how can I keep invoking my delete function after the first page (100 items) has been received.

My code looks like this, I know it is incomplete as this is the point I am stuck. I need to increment the `pageLeftOffSet` by 1 each time I have iterated over 100 items until there is nothing to iterate over which can be found in `products.meta.page.total`

```
function deleteAllProducts() {
    let pageLeftOffSet = 0;
    Moltin.Products.Sort('created_at')
        .Limit(100)
        .Offset(pageLeftOffSet)
        .All()
        .then(products => {
            while (products.meta.page.total > 0) {
                products.data.forEach((prod, index) => {
                    if (index == 100) {
                        pageLeftOffSet++
                    } else {
                        Moltin.Products.Delete(prod.id)
                            .then(success => {}).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err)
                            })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
}

deleteAllProducts()
```

Comment: This won't work for the last < 100 elements unless you definitely always have an amount divisible by 100 too right? Since the index of the last element won't be 100?

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are stuck about -- is there an error? What is the current behavior?

Comment: @ExpiredData That is correct my last page probably won't have exactly 100 items. But I can just do > 0 but thats is not my issue here. See my response to JonathanLam

Comment: @JonathanLam There is no error as my code runs... But I need some way of invoking the `deleteAllProducts()` function again after I have iterated over the 100 items it has finished with

Comment: So call deleteAllProducts() after the forEach is done? Probably needs some sort of Promise.all() to make sure all the deletes are done. But this seems like a really expensive way to delete things.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function recursively by passing the current `pageLeftOffset` + 1.

```
// take offset as param
function deleteAllProducts(pageLeftOffset) {

    Moltin.Products.Sort('created_at')
        .Limit(100)
        .Offset(pageLeftOffSet)
        .All()
        .then(products => {
            while (products.meta.page.total > 0) {
                products.data.forEach((prod, index) => {
                    if (index == 100) {

                        // recursive call
                        deleteAllProducts(pageLeftOffset + 1);

                    } else {
                        Moltin.Products.Delete(prod.id)
                            .then(success => {}).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err)
                            })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
}

// initial call with offset=0
deleteAllProducts(0);
```

Comment: You should update the check for whether to call the offset to test the size of products.data instead of the 100 (for the last page)

Comment: @ExpiredData But it shouldn't call itself on the last page, should it?

Comment: @JonathanLam No I was wrong with my original code the last page will need to be deleted too. so `products.meta.page.total > 0` will work. Let me give this a spin.